# Accessing RPL neighbors of each node at the root in Contiki-NG

Tags: contiki

Is there any way to access rpl neighbors of each node at the root of rpl network? I know nodes do not send neghbors to the root. But, is it possible to access each node's neighbor table as a global variable only in the simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Simulations also don't work like that - it is not possible to see the variables of another node from the perspective of a node's C code.

The best you can do is to implement periodic sending of the nodes' neighbor tables to the root.

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way to send neighbor tables of each node to the root? should I define a new control message like DAO in the network layer? Or do that in the application program and send it like a udp data packet?

Comment: @Heroshizen I'd suggest using UDP packets at the application layer. I you have fragmentation enabled, then you don't even need to worry too much about the packet size.